# What could be the possible reason for waveform distortion while connecting differential probe GND with single ended probe GND?

Tags: power-supply, oscilloscope, measurement, probe

I am measuring following waveforms using a DSO:

**Case 1:**
Waveform 1 wrt GND  using differtial probe.
Waveform 2 wrt GND using single ended probe.

**Result 1:** Waveform 1 distorted.

**Case 2:**
Waveform 1 wrt GND  using differtial probe.
Waveform 2 probe disconnected (both GND and active signal pin).

**Result 2:** Waveform 1 is clean.

Comment: Repeat case 1 with probe #2's GND clip connected and it should be the same thus indicating that an earth being connected to GND on your circuit upsets the circuit.